# How can I get rid of .DS_Store files that are stuck in remote repo?

Tags: git, macos, heroku

I have re-initialized my repos with the correct .gitignore files, however there are still .DS_Store files in my remote heroku.

A git pull heroku master gives:

[image]

How can I get rid of these files once and for all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look like you have commited those files already.

Once you add and commit files git starts to track them.

You have 2 main option to ignore those files.

1. Remove them from the repository (see the below code)
2. Use the ``assume-unchanged` flag to mark them as unchanged form this point on.

In your case you wish to use the first option so here is how.

> A `.gitignore` file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore.
>   **Files already tracked by Git are not affected**

---

### ***`How to remove commited files and set git to ignore them?`***

You have to remove & commit and then they will be ignored.

```
# remove the commited files:
git rm --cached .DS_Store

# now add the files to the .gitignore and

# commit and push
git commit -m "Removed..."
git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: I just git pushed with the -f option and this worked fine.

Comment: but if you did not remove the files they are still in the repository.

Comment: the file is in my .gitignore, so I think the force forced them to be erased on the remote.

Comment: No. it will not. clone the project to a new directory and you will see it.

Comment: The force will o only work if you have deleted, commit it and the forced push

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could pull down master and make sure that your working branch is clean, then remove `.DS_Store` files from your `.gitignore`, delete the `.DS_Store` files, commit the change, push it to master, then add the `.DS_Store` files to your `.gitignore` again and commit that.